# WebRTC Order of processing after onnegotiateneeded on getlocalmedia success

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, sdp

Have a webrtc environment up and running without any problem when i get usermedia before starting sessions (e.g., at initialize time). However, when i get the usermedia on session initiation and answer, i am not successful at adding the answer side media to the session (i.e., the initiating side video is visible at the answer side but the answer side video is not visible at the initiating side).
I have spent many hours trying to handle this without success and was hoping that someone could clarify a points on the processing of the onnegotiationneeded event.

Situation is as follows:

Side A initiates session, gets user media and once the usermedia is available and added to the peer connection, an SDP offer is generated and sent to the remote side.

Side B receives the offer, causes a ringing type event on screen and requests usermedia once the user decides to answer. The success call for the getusermedia adds a localdescription to the peer connection and at some point an onnegotiationeeded event is generated.

All seems to happen well (e.g., on side B - offer and candidates via the signaling channel, then have_remote_offer, remote stream added , etc..),

However, i am unclear whether the answering side should generate an SDP answer or an SDP offer after the renegotiation (i.e., when processing the onnegotiationneeded event).

Also, is it best to wait until the getusermedia returns a success before sending an SDP answer back, or should the SDP answer be sent based on the initiating side SDP offer, without waiting for the local usermedia and then sending another SDP (e.g., either offer or answer per the prior paragraph) after the onnegotiationneeded?

On a somewhat related question is the PRAnswer actually used - i have not seen such in the message traces.

Comment: i think you should add the local stream to the PeerConnection before you create the Answer SDP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On receiving an offer, side B needs to produce an answer, not an offer.

Side B should not be renegotiating during an answer, because it is already in the middle of a negotiation. In other words, you don't want `negotiationneeded` firing during an answer.

You say `negotiationneeded` is firing on side B. That is bad.

There may be three reasons it is firing, and without code I cannot tell which one:

1. You're adding the stream before calling `setRemoteDescription` with 
   the offer.
2. The number of video and/or audio tracks in your stream exceeds what's allowed in the offer.
3. You are using Chrome.

According to the spec, `negotiationneeded` only fires when the `signalingState` is `"stable"` (i.e. not negotiating), but not if `localDescription` at that time [matches what you've added ***and*** is allowed by the offer](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#clearing-negotiation-needed).

So ensure you're doing three things:

1. Call `setRemoteDescription(offer)` *before* adding the `getUserMedia` stream.
2. Unless both peers are adding the same number of video and/or audio tracks, use [`RTCOfferOptions`](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions) with `createOffer`.
3. In Chrome, be prepared to ignore `negotiationneeded` anyway, since it appears to have a bug where it fires outside of `"stable"` state, which will happen in this case.

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/yhqvaywu/) that works in Firefox and Chrome 45.

In Firefox you'll see:

```
addStream in have-remote-offer
checking
connected
```

whereas in Chrome 45 you'll see:

```
addStream in have-remote-offer
onnegotiationneeded fired in have-remote-offer
checking
connected
```

because of the bug.

Negotiation will still complete even if your answer has fewer tracks, so if you want to answer quickly, that is one way to go (but then you'll need to re-negotiate later when you add media).

`PRAnswer` is not implemented in any browser AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks very much - greatly appreciated. I am in fact using chrome and i do see the addstream in have-remote-offer then the onegotiationneeded fired.

Comment: Then, assuming that i answer without having gotten the local media on side B, the connection goes to a stable state and i later get the local media on side B and want to update the session, i assume that in this case, side B will send a new offer (and not a second answer as the state is stable).